# Parent container/panel for a CardLayout

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, cardlayout

How I can get the 'container' panel for any panel in `CardLayout`.

That is, if a panel is a card
in another 'container' panel, then how to get reference to this 'container' panel, from the card?

Here's what i am doing:-

```
public class LogInPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel implements ActionListener{

    /**
     * Creates new form Panel2
     */
   private JPanel parentPanel;
   private CardLayout c1=null;
    public LogInPanel() {
        initComponents();
        //c1=new CardLayout();
        parentPanel=(JPanel)(SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(this.getClass(), this));

        c1=(CardLayout)(parentPanel.getLayout());
        submitLogin.addActionListener(this);
    }
...
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  2) A card should not typically need to know the parent container.  It would be like 'the tail wagging the dog'.  Why do you (think you) need to?

Comment: Yep true .. Why do u need it?

Comment: I have put a button on a card(the card is defined by me, and extends JPanel).I want to show the next card upon clicking on it.But, I need to have access to the container class, since only a CardLayout object can call 'next()'.Also, I donot want to put a navigation bar in  the container since i need to access the data in the cards.

Comment: I don't understand the last sentence of that comment, but the rest of it says to me 'have a nested layout, with the `CardLayout` in the `CENTER` of a `BorderLayout`.  Put the controls in one of the other positions.  Don't extend ***any*** panels, but simply keep references to them if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method [getParent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getParent%28%29) that is provided by the `Component` superclass. For your panel that is a card, simply call `panel.getParent()` and it will give you the containing (parent) panel.

Comment: next, when i do : CardLayout c1=(CardLayout)panel.getParent.getLayout(), it throws a null pointer exception.

Comment: You might amend your question with a snippet of your code so we can evaluate what might be causing the NPE. In the particular snippet of code you have `panel.getParent.getLayout()`, but it should be `panel.getParent().getLayout()`. So it may be just that simple.