# displaying next card from a card itself in CardLayout

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, cardlayout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parent container/panel for a CardLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14659033/parent-container-panel-for-a-cardlayout)

How to display card panel from a card panel itself(whose layout is not CardLayout, but which is contained in a panel having CardLayout)?I don't want to put a separate navigation bar in the container as i need access to the card data.

Comment: Like I mentioned 3 hours ago on your other question.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Don't forget to add a question mark (?) to questions.

Comment: Please indicate how this question differs from your previous one on the same topic: [Parent container/panel for a CardLayout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14659033/parent-container-panel-for-a-cardlayout)

Answer (score 0):

You can access the parent component using getParent() method of your panel (this method is accessible from each AWT/Swing component). If your panel is not directly placed in a panel with card layout you should call this method iterative, until you get the panel you need.

Example:

```
Component myComp; // for example your navigation bar
Component parent = myComp.getParent();
while (null != parent) {
  if (parent.getLayout() instanceof CardLayout) {
    break;
  }
  parent = parent.getParent();
}
if (null != parent) {
  // now we have parent with the card layout
}
```